# Error in "Line 1, Column 1" of script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

We have a MasterPage Javascript which runs numerous times with no problems but a small number of times, from various pages, it generates the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" on Line 1, Column 1.

What could be causing this sporadic error? The file changes very rarely.

The browser is Chrome 66, this is an internal web application.

Comment: impossible to tell.... means something that is a script is not being returned as a script most likely.

Comment: This is usually a path reference error.  you're trying to pull down a script and are likely getting an html document back (like a 404 page), which is an invalid script.

Comment: I can understand that. Suggestions on how to debug this would be welcome.

Comment: click on the error message when it appears.... see what it is. Look at the sources in the network panel, see what failed

Comment: We get these recorded via errorception.com when it happens to a user, we have not been able to reproduce in our own testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be running before the page fully loads. 
Make sure to start the js file with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){...
```